# position of "appropriately"

Tags: adverb-placement

Where to put "appropriately" in the following sentence?

> Through the prism of BanDura, we can yoke different methodologies together to attain low computational complexity or the necessary level of security.

(Above, Bandura is a particular framework for describing programming methodologies.)

Here are some choices:

1. Through the prism of BanDura, we can appropriately yoke different methodologies together to attain low computational complexity or the necessary level of security.
2. Through the prism of BanDura, we can yoke different methodologies appropriately together to attain low computational complexity or the necessary level of security.
3. Through the prism of BanDura, we can yoke different methodologies together appropriately to attain low computational complexity or the necessary level of security.

It should be clear that putting the methodologies together needs to be done properly in order to attain the desired effects (low complexity or high securiy).

Btw., I have read [what Cambridge has to say](http://Adverbs%20and%20adverb%20phrases:%20position) about adverb placement, but cannot apply it to my situation. So, a grammar-based explanation would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a native speaker and I think, in your situation, all three mean the same thing.  There are times when the meaning can change, but in your example, I do not see a difference worth noting.  The first one would be heard more often, however.

Comment: No, I just went by the sound and I've heard it said all ways.  The rules are tough though.